# iOs7 onwards is it possible to develop iphone app with basic network management

Tags: iphone, swift, networking, ios7, mac-address

This is will my 1st iPhone app which i'm trying to develop using swift.

I want to monitor devices connected to my home router and **see how much bandwidth each devices connected to it is using.**

**My 1st question is - since ios7 onwards apple does allow to use MAC address of the device** so is there any other way to achieve to achieve my above requirement.

**My 2nd question** - is there any API or open-source library which can be used and apple will not reject the app if submitted.

Thanks,

Comment: If you are developing the app for your personal use only you can do whatever you want. Just install the app to your device using Xcode. Apple's guidelines only apply when submitting the app to the AppStore for distribution.

Comment: in future may plan to submit to AppStore.